# Dynamically assign value from controller to Vf Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have a page and controller, in Controller, there is a valiable named ColorCode which Stores Hexvalue of color, I want to assing this color code to my `<apex:outputText>`.

My vf Page:

```
<apex:page controller="AdminPanelSuccessController">
    <style>
    .backgroundColor {
        background-color: {!colorCode};
    }
    </style>

    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        -----------
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <div style="text-align:center;font-size: 25px;">
                            <apex:outputLabel id="ol1" value="BACKGROUND COLOR :" >
                                <apex:outputText value="{!colorCode}" styleClass="backgroundColor" />
                            </apex:outputLabel>
                            <apex:outputLabel>
                            {!colorCode}
                            </apex:outputLabel>
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                </table>

           </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**My controller:**

```
public class AdminPanelSuccessController {

    public string imageURL{get;set;}
    public String colorCode{get;set;}
    public string callfunc{get;set;}
    public string metaData{get;set;}
    public List<brand__mdt> BrandTypes = new List<brand__mdt>();
    //public static AdminPannelController mainController{get;set;}

    public AdminPanelSuccessController(){
        System.debug('metadata' +metaData);

        String documentId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('docId');
        colorCode = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('colorCode');
        System.debug(documentId);
        System.debug(colorCode);

        List<Document> lstDocument = [Select Id,Body from Document where Id =: documentId limit 1];
        System.debug(lstDocument);
        if(lstDocument.size() > 0){
             imageURL= lstDocument[0].id;
        }
         callfunc='<script> hexToRgbA(); </script>';
    }
}
```

How to show color from colorCode?

Comment: What is not working here, Are you getting any error?

Comment: Not getting colorCode

Comment: Are you getting `colorCode` value in `debug logs`?

Comment: yes, i am getting the value of colorCode in string "FFAA24"

Comment: You want to show the color code value in that color right?

Comment: yes, i want to show color from these color codes

Comment: `FFAA24` is not a valid color hex code, you need a # before that. So make sure you pass `#FFAA24` in the URL.

Comment: And instead passing `#` in url you can directly add this in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an answer, just so the thread can be closed.

`FFAA24` is not a valid color hex code, you need a # before that. So make sure you pass `#FFAA24` in the URL or append the `#` character to the `colorCode` variable.